# shopify ajax products in collection

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to build a Vue module on my shopify site so I created a jSON endpoint for the collections:

```
{% layout none %}
{% paginate collection.products by settings.pagination_limit %}
   {
     "results": {{ collection.products | json }}
   }
{% endpaginate  %}
```

when I visit that endpoint at /collections/collection-slug?view=json I get a full dump of all the products but when I ajax all I get is the collection object with no nested products.

My ajax:

```
$.getJSON('/collections/mens-slip-on?view=json', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    that.products = response;
  });
```

My result:

```
Object {collection: Object}

collection:Object
description:(...)
handle:(...)
id:(...)
image:(...)
products_count:(...)
published_at:(...)
title:(...)
updated_at:(...)
```

My Vue component in full:

```
new Vue({
 el: '#filterable',
 data: {
 collection: null,
 products: null
},

mounted() {
  this.initCollection();
  this.fetchProducts();
},

methods: {

initCollection: function() {
  var currPath = window.location.pathname;
  this.collection = currPath.substring(currPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
},

fetchProducts: function() {
  var that = this;

  $.getJSON('/collections/mens-slip-on?view=json',        function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    that.products = response;
  }); 
 }

}

});

Vue.config.devtools = true;
```

It appears that no matter what I put in my collection.json.liquid template it always returns the collection object.

UPDATE: I was able to solve this by using XHR instead of jQuery to do the ajax call. It appears the issue is somehow related to jQuery getJSON but I'm not clear on the reason for this.

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
  httpRequest.open('GET', '/collections/' + this.collection + '?view=json', true);
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  httpRequest.send();

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);

        parent.products = response.results;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add more vuejs related code ?

Comment: The Vue js code is irrelevant, I'm just calling a method that runs that ajax call.

Comment: What is relevant then ? :) When you make GET request to that api endpoint in Postman (hope you use it), what you get ?

Comment: @KevinCompton uhm. what? he's just trying to help, calm down. I also read your question, and have some of the same questions. You haven't provided the json that is being produced, only the resulting... console output? it's unclear whether that's an object, an array of objects, or what. Or what theobject.collections contains (other than a non-descrip object)

Comment: The only relavant thing is fact that other folks on Stackoverflow doesn't know the background of your project and It's data structure.
If visited endpoint in browser return corrects data, but the jQuery ajax method doesn't then maybe is problem on front-end side - that's why I asked about response in Postman and more front-end related code.Just my 2c, good luck with finding solution !

Comment: Sorry guys I'm adding more details above, i added the collection object props but as you can see there are no nested products. Also it seems to return this object no matter what I put in the template, so I have a feeling its never even hitting that jSON for some reason

Comment: @BelminBedak apologies, I added the Vue component I see your point now.

Comment: so, it sounds like at this point your problem may lie at shopify. If browsing directly to `/collections/mens-slip-on?view=json` doesn't give you what you expect, something isn't setup properly on the backend.

Comment: @KevinB Browsing directly to that path DOES give me what I expect.

Comment: hmm... that.. doesn't seem possible. If that's the case, your endpoint is correct, are you sure your url is correct? something isn't matching.

Comment: @KevinB I'm putting in that path in the ajax call, all I get back is the collection object and it doesn't matter what I have in the template file.

Comment: Can you add this after the callback function? `, "json"` it shouldn't have an impact, but it'l at least force json if for whatever reason it's using jsonp.

Comment: @KevinB you mean like this? Made no difference.... $.getJSON('/collections/mens-slip-on?view=json', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        that.products = response;
      }, "json");

Comment: Can you compare your network tab request headers when making the request via ajax and browsing directly?

Comment: @KevinB the only thing I see that's different is the ajax request gives me Referer:https://inkkas.com/collections/mens-slip-on, html request has no referer...

Comment: And the response bodies are different?

Comment: @KevinB Yep. Totally stumped. It doesn't even matter what's in that template I always just get the collection object for ajax.

Comment: wait. we're getting somewhere, lets move this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142020/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-kevin-compton).

Comment: Thanks for updating this. Was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your call is incorrect.

Should be something more like

```
$.getJSON('/collections/mens-slip-on.json', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    that.products = response;
  });
```

That will return the collection object in json format. If you want all the products you would need

```
$.getJSON('/collections/mens-slip-on/products.json', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    that.products = response;
  });
```

Comment: no this isn't how it's documented, I'm using the template switch variable 'view=template_name'

Comment: /collections/mens-slip-on/products.json - this products.json endpoint only gives 30 products. Add &limit=100 and there will be more products returned